# '@JsonProperty' not applicable to type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an example of a JSON I want to send:

```
{"lat":41.562592,"long":-8.430022}'
```

And I need to refer to the second property, like this:

```
@JsonProperty('long')
private String longitude;
```

But in the first like of this second code segment, I get an error:

```
'@JsonProperty' not applicable to type
```

Is it possible to refer to that second property, as `long`, in Jackson, or do I need to rename it with a key not equal to a Java variable type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `String` for `@JsonProperty`

try

```
@JsonProperty("long")
```